# Strimzi kafka accessing it privately with in GKE

Tags: apache-kafka, strimzi

I have two clusters,

one cluster with my application Microservices and other with the strimzi kafka installed. Both are the private GKE clusters .

My challenge exactly is to how to connect to this kafka from my application. There are around 10 Microservices running each has to connect to the kafka.

I have an approach for now by making the Strimzi kafka as a Nodeport service and providing the Ip and nodeIp in the application code.

The problem with this approach is that if the GKE nodes get auto updated I will have to reconfigure the code.

Also one more critical condition is that , The Kafka should be only accessed by our application ., It shouldn't be available for the public Internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar situation and how I solved it.

Create an internal loadbalancer to be accessible from another AKS cluster. Also allowing access to specific subnet as well.

Strimzi supports externalizing the bootstrap service.

example:

```
...
spec:
  kafka:
    replicas: 3
    listeners:
      plain: {}
      tls: {}
      external:
        type: loadbalancer
        tls: false
    ...
    template:
      externalBootstrapService:
          metadata:
            annotations:
              service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
              service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal-subnet: "apps-subnet"
      perPodService:
        metadata:
          annotations:
            service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
            service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal-subnet: "apps-subnet"
```

for more details you can check ***internal load balancers*** section in this link:
https://strimzi.io/blog/2019/05/13/accessing-kafka-part-4/

Comment: Can you please elaborate @amjad .? Which all files you edited for the setup ..

Comment: I hope you followed the tutorial when setting up the strimzi operator. After the Strimzi operator is deployed you need to pass the mentioned configuration when creating the kafka-cluster like this: https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/quickstart.html#proc-kafka-cluster-str
i have updated my answer as well.

Comment: What is the version of strimzi kafka you are using .? @amjad.

Comment: 0.24.0 is the strimzi version

Comment: Kafka is up and running with internally load balanced IP however not able to communicate from other cluster. Any idea what could be the issue.?

Comment: i'm not sure how your both GKE clusters are setup make sure to have connectivity between the two networks, so that you can be able to make connection to the internal load balancer

Comment: ` version: 2.7.0
    replicas: 3
    listeners:
      - name: external
        port: 9094
        type: loadbalancer
        tls: true
        authentication:
          type: tls
        configuration:
          bootstrap:
            annotations:
              cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
              networking.gke.io/internal-load-balancer-subnet: "test"
          brokers:
          - broker: 0
            annotations:
              cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
              networking.gke.io/internal-load-balancer-subnet: "test"`

Comment: Above is what the configuration i am using. I am able to curl the private ip from the other cluster however only kafka is what i am unable to connect, Getting the error "Timed out waiting for node assignment" - Any thoughts on the same.?

Comment: Making tls : false resolved the issue .,